Не запускается телеграм-бот
Вот сам код
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('токен')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text', 'document', 'audio'])

def get_messages(message):
  if message.text == 'Привет':
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Привет, ты сегодня пил кофе? Оно помогает от альцгеймера!')
  elif message.text == 'Кто тебя создал?':
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Меня создал Великий Максим!')
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Вот что он говорил при создании: "Чем я занимаюсь..."')
  else:
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Не понял, что ты пишешь, но тебе надо выпить кофе! Оно, кстати, помогает от альцгеймера!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
     bot.polling(none_stope=True)


Но когда я пишу в консоли python bot.py или python3 bot.py то в консоли выводится слово Python, а бот при этом не запускается, что делать?

У вас консоль на магазин приложений windows пытается вас перенаправить. Проверьте, что python вообще установлен, через этот магазин, а еще лучше - с официального сайта скачать и установить.
